# which version of vue.js is required by vuesax?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuesax

I want to use vuesax on my first project and I fell in love with vuesax components. I am actually using Vue cli 2.

Which version of Vue is required by vuesax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vuesax` [3.x](https://github.com/lusaxweb/vuesax/blob/3f03427/package.json#L50) and [4.x](https://github.com/lusaxweb/vuesax-next/blob/3c09e71/package.json#L17) depend on Vue 2.

So `vuesax` projects need the latest version of Vue 2 in your project (currently 2.6.14):

```sh
npm i -S vue@2
```